# C++ Specialized constructor of class without template arguments (skip angle brackets)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following template function:

```
template<typename T>
T test_function(T arg) {return arg;}
```

I can create a specialized version of this for integers with:

```
template<>
int test_function(int arg) {return arg;}
```

This is practical if I use this function with integers a lot. So I can call it with:

```
test_function(some_integer);      // easy!
test_function<int>(some_integer); // not necessary all the time.
```

Now I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
};
```

I want to be able to call it with:

```
Foo foo1;       // how do I do this?
Foo<int> foo2;  // I don't want to use this all the time.
```

How can I define this class in order to be able to create an instance of it without using angle brackets at all? Shouldn't be too hard I think, but I couldn't figure it out so far...

Comment: You don't have to create the specialization of `test_function` for `int` (unless it's doing something different), it can infer the type from the argument.

Comment: Construct it through a make_ function with deduces the argument type. See std::make_tuple for an example.

Comment: @AntonSavin Ah I see, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @RichardHodges I will check this out!

Answer (score 2):

You should either use default argument (int) and then:

```
template<typename T = int> class Foo {};
Foo<> foo2;
```

or make an alias:

```
using MyFoo = Foo<int>; //or just Foo<> if using default argument
MyFoo foo1;
```

I believe you cannot create an object of templated class without indicating that it is a template class even when all template arguments have defaults.

NOTE: `using` is C++11 keyword, use `typedef` for legacy code/compilers.

Comment: Hmm ok, I did it like this so far. The reason I'd prefer it to have without brackets is to make the use of this class easier. Thanks for the alias hint, I think I'll go with this if there is no other solution.

Comment: @donald It's the standard way of doing this. `using` is actually really nice and it exists primarily for this purpose. Its syntax is also better and more consistent than `typedef` and can be nested within a class: `class A { public: using B = SomeClass; }` and then `A::B` is a valid type (alias to `SomeClass`).

Comment: It's worth noting that `typedef` is by all means equivalent to corresponding `using` declaration, in particular it can also be nested within a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
T test_function(T arg) {return arg;}

template<>
int test_function<int>(int arg) {return arg;}
```

Comment: Yes, this works too for the function example, but how can I do it for the class?

Comment: class functions can be specialized outside class like this:
`template<> MyClass<int>::MyClass() { /*constructor, specific for int*/}`